# video tag - log onplay clicks into a database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, video

I am trying to record the number of times a video is played and saving it into a database field, to on phpmyadmin to be used next someone clicks the video, in order to keep a total number of times the video has been played.

So far I have been able to record the number of times a video is played through the console.log (see comments section /add to video count each time play is pressed). However I can't seem to figure out how to (//update video count to database) or (//select current video count from database)

```
 <video class="spotted" controls><source src="nora-hello.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>

<?php
 include("../db_conn.php");

 $videoName = document.getElementById("nora-hello");

//select current video count from database
 $qry_stringVC = "select * from `video-count` where `videoName` = '?'";
 $prepVC = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_stringVC);  
 $prepVC->execute(array($videoName)); 
 $resultVC = $prepVC->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $VCid = $resultVC['video-count'];
 console.log($VCid);
 ?>

//add to video count each time play is pressed
 $VC1 = 0;
 const video = document.querySelector('video');
 let a = $VC1;
 video.onplay = (event) => {
 a++;
console.log(a); // 2
 $a = a;
 console.log($a);
console.log($VCid);
 <?php

//update video count to database
$sqlVC = "update `video-count` set `videoCount` = ? where `video-countID` = ?";
$qcVC = $pdo_conn->prepare($sqlVC);
 $qcVC->execute(array($a, $VC));
 console.log("saved");

?>
 };
</script>
```

I have also tried this, however the console.log($VCid) is coming up empty:

```
<video class="spotted" id="nora-hello" controls><source src="nora-hello.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
//add to video count each time play is pressed
$VC1 = 0;
const video = document.querySelector('video');
let a = $VC1;
video.onplay = (event) => {
a++;
$a = a;
console.log($a);

$videoName = $(video).attr('id');
console.log($videoName);

      // notice the quotes around the ?php tag         
      // var htmlString="<?php //echo $VCid; ?>";
      // alert(htmlString);
};
</script>

  <?php 
include("../db_conn.php");
$qry_stringVC = "select `videoCount` from `video-count` where `videoName` = '?'";
$prepVC = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_stringVC);  
$prepVC->execute(array($videoName)); 
$resultVC = $prepVC->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$VCid = $resultVC['videoCount'];

// $sqlVC = "update `video-count` set `videoCount` = ? where `video-countID` = ?";
// $qcVC = $pdo_conn->prepare($sqlVC);
// $qcVC->execute(array($a, $VCid));
 ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> console.log($VCid);</script>
```

Comment: I added javascript as a tag to get more attention as this is a javascript question since you are looking to use something like fetch or jquery ajax etc to submit the data to the server.

Comment: @imvain2 Thank you and *fingers crossed* someone comes up with a fix

Comment: you can look up JavaScript fetch or jquery Ajax